# Overriding Session Controller Prevents custom views being used

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise, custom-view

Devise (2.1) was using my custom views fine until I told it to use a custom controller. Now it ignores my custom views.

**Previously everything worked fine:**

Tell Devise to use custom views in `/config/devise.rb`

```
# ==> Scopes configuration
# Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
# "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
# are using only default views.
config.scoped_views = true
```

Add custom view: `/app/views/subscribers/session/new.html.erb`

Set up routes in `/config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :subscribers
```

**Then I added a custom SubscriberSessionsController** as `/app/controllers/subscriber_session_controller.rb`

```
class SubscriberSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    before_filter :isInIframe

    private

        def isInIframe
            @hide_navbar = session[:in_iframe]
        end

end
```

And modified /config/routes.rb to tell Devise to use this new controller instead of its default:

```
devise_for :subscribers, :controllers => { 
    :sessions => "subscriber_sessions"
  }
```

**Once I restart my server, Devise now uses this controller but ignores my custom view.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is so often the case, ten minutes after posting the question I cracked it.

The reason Devise wasn't finding the view was it was looking for it in a different folder.My replacement controller was called `subscriber_sessions.rb`so devise was no longer looking in `views/subscribers/sessions` but `views/subscribers/subscriber_sessions`.

I solved this problem with the following:

Changed my subscriber routes to:

```
  devise_for :subscribers, :controllers => { 
    :sessions => "subscribers/sessions"
  }
```

Renamed my subscriber_sessions controller to just sessions and moved it into a subscribers folder so its new name & location are: `app/controllers/subscribers/sessions_controller.rb`

I also had to add a namespace to the class so the new sessions_controller.rb file looks like this"

```
class Subscribers::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    before_filter :isInIframe

    private

        def isInIframe
            @hide_navbar = session[:in_iframe]
        end

end
```

Comment: This is still the case for Rails 4 and Devise 3.5, the template path must match the class name. You should accept your answer as correct.